# Java Focus Event Listener

Tags: java, events, focus

I was wondering how to add a focus gained event listener.

At the moment I have a Mouse Event which is being added to my
JTextareas

```
   //=======================================================
   // mouse drag event
   //=======================================================

   public static class genDrag extends MouseMotionAdapter {
      JTextArea textarea;

      // receive textarea as argument
      public genDrag(JTextArea argTextarea) {
         textarea = argTextarea;
      }

      // add drag functionality to argument
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent E) {
         Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(textarea, E.getPoint(), gc_gui.cv_content);
         textarea.setBounds((p.x - 40), (p.y - 15), 100, 30);
      }
   }
```

which I can then call using

```
   //=======================================================
   // apply mouse event
   //=======================================================
   JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
   textarea.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 30);
   textarea.addMouseMotionListener(new genDrag(textarea));
```

this works fine but I have been unable to reproduce the same
functionality for a focusGained event

```
   //=======================================================
   // mouse focus event
   //=======================================================

   public static class genFocus extends EventListener {
      JTextArea textarea;

      public genFocus() {
         textarea = argTextarea;
      }

      public void focusGained(FocusEvent E) {
        System.out.println("Focus Triggered");
      }
   }
```

The above doesn't seem happy at all

*UPDATING CODE*

```
static gui classGui;

public static void main(String[] args) {

   classGui = new gui();

   classGui.textarea.addMouseMotionListener(
       new genDrag(classGui.textarea)
   );

   classGui.textarea.addFocusListener(
      new genFocus(this)
   );

   classGui.frame.setVisible(true);

   public static class gui {
       JFrame frame;
       JPanel panel;
       JTextArea textarea;

       public gui() {
           frame = new JFrame();
           // configure JFrame here

           panel = new JPanel();
           // configure JPanel here

           textarea = new JTextArea();
           textarea.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 30);

           frame.add(textarea);
      }

   }

   public static class genDrag extends MouseMotionAdapter {
       JTextArea textarea;

       public genDrag(JTextArea argTextarea) {
           textarea = argTextarea;
       }

       public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent E) {
           Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(textarea, E.getPoint(), gc_gui.cv_content);
           textarea.setBounds((p.x - 40), (p.y - 15), 100, 30);
       }
   }

   public static class genFocus implements FocusListener {
       JTextArea textarea;

       public genFocus(JTextArea argTextarea) {
           textarea = argTextarea;
       }

       public void focusGained(FocusEvent E) {
          System.out.println("Focus gained");
       }

       public void focusLost(FocusEvent E) {
          System.out.println("Focus lost");
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle focus events, your handler needs to implement the `FocusListener` interface instead of `EventListener`.
Note that you need to add this handler via the `addFocusListener`. I don't think you did this, because if you had done this, you would have gotten a compiler error indicating what was wrong.

Use of the `@Override` annotation helps finding such errors. Put it above every method you think should override a parent method. If such a method does not actually override another method, the compiler will throw an error. This way you get informed of the mistake instead of your program failing silently.

Comment: I think I've made the change you suggested

Comment: No o_o it doesn't like the genFocus class

Comment: @Trent: FocusListener has two methods, focusGained and focusLost. If you don't implement both, you'll get a compiler error, because when implementing an interface, you need to implement all of its methods. This does not happen for the other handler, because there you extend a class.

Comment: I've added the focusLost bit

Comment: Does it work now? If not, what is happening? In case of a compiler error, which one? It's hard to guess what is wrong just from the code.

Comment: It works now, it seems it was just the missing focusLost method that was causing the compile to fail. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

you should add a `event-listener` to the control `JTextArea` then only it will be able to handle any `event` request.

```
JTextField textarea= new JTextField("Value");
textarea.addFocusListener(new genFocus(textarea)); //this peice of code will add an listener to you textarea Object of JTextField.
```

Your Mouse Listener will work because you have added a mouse event listener to your `JTextArea`.

```
textarea.addMouseMotionListener(new genDrag(textarea));//code to add MouseMotionListener.
```

but there is no `FocusEvent` is registerd with your `JTextArea`.

Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my code closer to what I think you mean

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) is exactly what you need...

Just a hint: your class genFocus (prefer to follow code conventions: GenFocus) should implement FocusListener.

Comment: @Trent Your code as should not have compiled at all - you haven't implemented focusLost. Additionally, your ctor does not match to how your are calling it...

Comment: No it doesn't compile, I didn't know I needed to implement focusLost

Comment: I've added the focusLost bit

Comment: @Trent That is inherent to interfaces - all their functions are implicitely abstract. And if any function is abstract (inherited or explicitely defined), a class cannot be instantiated. Instead, subclasses have to provide an appropriate implementation on their own, and these can then be instantiated.

Comment: Could you please give me an example

Comment: @Trent Well, you have already one: FocusListener. It is an interface, which is why you have to use 'implements' instead of extends. As being an interface, you have to implement both methods provided, focusGained and focusLost - as you did now, and which looks fine now. Problem left: `new genFocus(this)`. I do not assume that your class containing main inherits from JTextArea - does it? If so, compilation fails, if it actually inherits, your monitoring another JTextArea than the one you want to. Do `new genFocus(classGui.textArea)` as you did already for the mouse listener.